# Обработать входные json данные NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, express

Только начать использовать VK Callback api. Там при работе на мой сервер приходит json запрос, который я должен разобрать и обработать. Как выбрать из json параметр type?

```
app.post("/callback", (req, res) => {
res.writeHead(200);
let data = req.query;
console.log(data);
let user_id = 168034338; // data.object.user_id
switch (data.type) {
    case "confirmation":
        res.send(confirmationToken);
        break;
}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо декодировать json-ответ JSON.parse(). Далее выбираем нужный вам элемент из массива.

Comment: Что передавать в аргумент JSON.parse()? req.body не действует.

Comment: в функцию надо передать json-ответ от сервера VK. посмотрите что вообще приходит в req.body